# drupal call ajax function

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

> $delete_commant = l(t('X'), $url, array('attributes' =>
>   array('onclick' => 'return call_ajax(123)')));

when i put alert in call_ajax function definition, it is alerted, so i proceed to write the ajax post method, but when i click the link page getting refresh,

How to implement ajax in drupal

```
function call_ajax(str){alert(str);
    var url = "post.php";
    var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);  
     }
```

Comment: i think so you are not initializing var http.

Comment: atleast it should show that error know, but when i  click X, its simply refreshing the page

Comment: did you try it with initializing look in this example they are initializing var xmlhttp;http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: try console.log instead of alert if you had firebug in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal uses jquery by default.  So why not just implement this call using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Other techniques involve using the form_api like the ahah : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah

Comment: provide one example which perform operation, when i click the x i want to do delete process in the back ground and once the delete is completed need one alert message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have return false in your onclick handler. But you should learn [a bit more about jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).